# Prime number generation using Parallel loop

Tags: c#

I am writing a parallel loop for generating primes

```
Parallel.For(0, maxNumber, (i, loopState) =>
{
    if (IsPrime((UInt32)i))
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref primesFound);
        if (primesFound > maxPrimes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(“Last prime found: {0:N0}”,i);
            loopState.Stop();
        }
    }
});
```

Can somebody explain me how this works especially what is the use of loopstate here and what if i dont' want it.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I think his problem is he found the code online and needs to understand it and document it before handing it in for his parallel studies class?

Comment: not problem i just want to understand how this works?

Comment: MSDN documentation for the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Well, the good news is that you can double your loop performance by doing `IsPrime((UInt32)((i*2)+1))` and handling 2 manually....

Comment: Can here i just need to put problem questions only?

Comment: Look at [MSDN: Stop or Break from a Parallel.For Loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721(v=vs.110).aspx). (_"loopState is a compiler-generated [`ParallelLoopState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate(v=vs.110).aspx)... which allows to stop or break the loop"_)

Comment: @TimSchmelter it is incorrect to say that it is "compiler-generated". It is library-provided.

Comment: @MarcGravell: thanks for pointing that out. However, it's also addressed to the guy from MS who wrote the sample on MSDN, it was just a quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loopState` is provided for you by `Parallel.ForEach`, and is a `ParallelLoopState` instance that lets you do things like stop the iteration - useful when you have found all the data you were looking for. If you didn't need it, just use the overload that doesn't expose it:

```
Parallel.For(0, maxNumber, i => {
   // ....
});
```